Send multiple attachments with gmail in R
I have multiple lists which look like this:
list(structure(list(mail = c("yo@yo.com", "yo@yo.com", "yo@yo.com", 
"yo@yo.com", "yo@yo.com", "yo@yo.com", "yo@yo.com"), file = c("file1.pdf", 
"file2.pdf", "file3.pdf", "file4.pdf", "file5.pdf", "file6.pdf", 
"file7.pdf")), row.names = c(NA, 7L), class = "data.frame"))

As you can see, it's the same email but with multiples files associated to it. So what I want is to attach all this files at once when I create a draft considering that for every email, the number of files won't be the same. Since that can't be done directly with gm_attach_file() i'm trying to use purrr::reduce().
When I execute:
files_vector <- data.frame(arc= test[[1]][[2]])
purrr::reduce(.x = files_vector, .f = gm_attach_file)

I get all the files I want to send:
[1] "file1.pdf" "file2.pdf" "file3.pdf" "file4.pdf" "file5.pdf" "file6.pdf" "file7.pdf"

I must say that:
files_vector <- data.frame(arc= test[[1]][[2]])

doesn't work with my original data since I got this error:
Error in mime$parts : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors

When I run the whole code for creating an email, I just got an empty draft with no recipient and no attached files at all.
gm_mime()|>
    gm_to(sprintf("%s", unique(test[[1]][[1]])))|>
    gm_from("tu@tu.com") |>
    gm_subject("The files you requested")|>
gm_html_body(body = paste(glue::glue(
    "<h5><b> <b></h5>
    <p>
    <p> </p>
    <p> .</p>"

)))|>
    purrr::reduce(.x = files_vector, .f = gm_attach_file)|>
    gm_create_draft()

I don't know if I'm doing something wrong or it's simply that gmailr is somewhat limited on how many files you could attach to an email. Any feedback will be much appreciated.
I must add that I also reviewed this: How to send multiple attachments and images(in mail) body using GmailR package? and the solution it's given there doesn't work at all.

I don't have credentials setup so I can't fully test this, but I think this should work.
library(gmailr)

test <- list(structure(list(mail = c("yo@yo.com", "yo@yo.com", "yo@yo.com", 
                                     "yo@yo.com", "yo@yo.com", "yo@yo.com", "yo@yo.com"), 
                            file = c("file1.pdf", 
                                     "file2.pdf", "file3.pdf", "file4.pdf", "file5.pdf", "file6.pdf", 
                                     "file7.pdf")), 
                            row.names = c(NA, 7L), class = "data.frame"))


prepare_email <- function(mail, files){
    base_email <- gm_mime()|>
        gm_to(mail) |>
        gm_from("tu@tu.com") |>
        gm_subject("The files you requested")|>
        gm_html_body(body = paste(glue::glue(
            "<h5><b> <b></h5>
    <p>
    <p> </p>
    <p> .</p>"
            
        )))
    
    purrr::reduce(.x = files, .f = gm_attach_file, .init = base_email)
}

ready_to_send <- test[[1]] |>
    dplyr::as_tibble() |> 
    dplyr::summarise(.by = mail, files = list(file)) |> 
    purrr::pmap(prepare_email)
    

I use dplyr to create a pair of lists (columns of the tibble) and use purrr to map through them.  The prepare_email function first prepares the base email without the attachments.  Then I use purrr::reduce to attach the files.  Specify the base email with the .init parameter.
